# Cmake Custom target that runs only once

Tags: c++, build, cmake, code-generation

I need to somehow generate `.fidl` files based on `.cpp` and `.hpp` files.
The problem is that if I try to use `add_custom_target` it runs every time.
For `add_custom_command` I need specify output files, but I do not want to do it.
I'd like to do something like this:

```
add_custom_command(gen_fidl
                   DEPENDS "*.fidl"
                   COMMAND <My Commands>)
```

But in this case I need specify a rule for `.fidl` files

How would I be able to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the following solution:

```
add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT fidl_generated_successfully
        DEPENDS ./cmake-build-debug/*.fidl
        COMMAND touch fidl_generated_successfully
        COMMAND <COMMAND TO DO>)

add_custom_target(
        fidl_gen
        DEPENDS fidl_generated_successfully)

add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} fidl_gen)
```

But the issue there is the generation on the file (**fidl_generated_successfully**).
Are there anywhere better solution without creating useless file **fidl_generated_successfully**

Answer (score 1):

The general answer is following:
If you don't know which files are generated, you should use approach with "fake" file like Denis Kotov suggested.
Otherwise something like that is better:

```
# definition of fidl_list
add_custom_command( OUTPUT ${fidl_list}
    DEPENDS ${input_files_or_folders_for_generation}
    COMMAND <command_to_do> )

add_custom_target(fidl_gen DEPENDS ${fidl_list})
```